# Small and cheap mini-PC to install Linux (no desktop environment) and a development LAMP webserver

Tags: linux, development, mini-pc, web-development

I manage a LAMP website, which I develop at home, and then I upload the changes to the production public server.

I am trying to find a small and cheap fanless PC to install Linux and my development LAMP server. I was considering 200-300 USD mini PCs, like Kangaroo MD2B Mobile Desktop Computer, Intel NUC based MiniPCs, QOTOM-Q310G4 Barebone Mini PC, etc. I will install only a Linux distro (without any desktop environment), with Apache, PHP, MySQL, and Samba.

Any recommendation is welcome.

Comment: Deleting and re-asking your question because it was closed is *not* the way to do it. Your question was closed for a reason; address that reason with some edits, and it may be reopened. Don't just re-ask it.